# Starfleet officer promotions (Prime universe only)

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, starfleet-rank

Given that in Star Trek Discovery we don't yet know for certain if Tilly will be the XO at the start of the next season and she (currently) holds the rank of ensign, is there any precedent in the **Prime universe only** for someone being promoted by 2 or more ranks in one go (excluding cadets getting battlefield promotions as on the Valiant, or someone who left Starfleet rejoining with a higher rank than what they left)?

Comment: Melissa Flores was promoted straight from being a civilian to being First Officer; https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Marissa_Flores

Comment: @Valorum i do doubt that was an official promotion tho

Comment: XO isn't a rank

Comment: The brevet promotions on the Valiant were illegal anyway.

Comment: Tom Paris went from cadet to (presumably) ensign to dishonourably discharged to lieutenant, though that was a field commission so might not be in the spirit of the question even though his commission wasn’t, strictly speaking, in “battle”.

Answer (score 2):

Kirk went from captain to admiral which could be considered multiple grades depending on how the rank list actually goes.

To be fair though an XO can technically be any rank of course having an ensign as an XO would be an interesting situation.

Comment: It's not really clear whether the intervening grades of Admiral are actually requirements though.

Comment: I believe he was addressed as a rear admiral.

Comment: In _Lower Decks_ Mariner becomes "number 1" for an episode at the rank of Ensign. They do appear to have Commodores in Star Fleet so a promotion from Captain to Admiral would indeed be skipping a rank.

Comment: Oh, and since we see no Able Spacemen, Leading Rates or Petty Officers, Miles O'Brien must have skipped a bunch of ranks to be a Chief Petty Officer too.